# SQL dealing with duplicate records by date difference

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a table like so:

```
id     start_date      end_date
01     2012-03-15    2012-04-02
01     2012-04-05    2012-05-12
01     2012-04-12    2012-05-21
02     2012-03-05    2012-06-13
03     2012-03-09    2012-03-19
03     2012-05-15    2012-08-01
```

The definition of duplicate records here is any multitude of rows with the same id AND whose start_dates are within 31 days of each other. In the above example, row 2, 3 are duplicates of 1 and row 6 is NOT a duplicate of row 5. I'd like to remove the duplicates to get:

```
id     start_date      end_date
01     2012-03-15    2012-04-02
02     2012-03-05    2012-06-13
03     2012-03-09    2012-03-19
03     2012-05-15    2012-08-01
```

I wonder if this kind of filtering is better done in python after the data has been collected with duplicates or if there is an easy way to do it in sql.

Comment: Can you have duplicate start_dates for each ID? (And, if so, how do you decide which is the duplicate?)

Comment: No. There won't be duplicates for the same start_date and same id.

Comment: You could brute force it in python with minimal code, iterate over all rows, if the date <31 days to the prior row and the id is the same delete the row.  That is easy to code.  Then it depends on performance, the iteration will probably be slow in python.

Comment: To do it in SQL, you'd need to do the same sort of iteration over each row (either through a cursor/loop or a recursive CTE). I'm not sure how efficient it would be in comparison to doing it through python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have to use some sort of recursion regardless of which language you choose. Here's an example of how you could do it in SQL:

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (ID INT, start_date DATE, end_date DATE);
INSERT @ VALUES (1,'2012-03-15','2012-04-02')
, (1,'2012-04-05','2012-05-12')
, (1, '2012-04-12', '2012-05-21')
, (2, '2012-03-05', '2012-06-13')
, (3, '2012-03-09', '2012-03-19')
, (3, '2012-04-03', '2012-05-02')
, (3, '2012-05-01', '2012-08-01')
, (3, '2012-05-16', '2012-08-02')
, (3, '2012-06-08', '2012-09-09');

WITH T AS (
    SELECT id, start_date, end_date, RN
    FROM (
        SELECT id, start_date, end_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date) RN
        FROM @) S
    WHERE RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT S.id
         , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, T.start_date, S.start_date) <= 31 THEN T.start_date ELSE S.start_date END
         , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, T.start_date, S.start_date) <= 31 THEN T.end_date ELSE S.end_date END
         , S.RN
    FROM (
        SELECT id, start_date, end_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date) RN
        FROM @) S
    JOIN T ON T.id = S.id
    WHERE S.RN = T.RN+1
    )
SELECT id, start_date, end_date
FROM T
GROUP BY id, start_date, end_date;
```

Which works fine for a not-large-at-all sample size, but if you're looking at a lot of rows, it's probably not the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: I think I will be doing this in python.